# While Migrating database it shows error Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'domain_status'

Tags: database, laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-7

[image]

I dont know how to resolve this

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDomainsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return voidzz
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('domains', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('domain')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->string('google_domain')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->string('location')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->string('device')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            // $table->string('Hl')->nullable();
            // $table->string('Gl')->nullable();
            $table->string('hl')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->string('gl')->collate('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->integer('domain_status')->default('active')->nullable();
            $table->integer('update_frequency')->nullable();
            $table->timestampsTz();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('domains');
    }
}
```

Comment: please share create_domains_table migration code

Answer (score 2):

You define `domain_status` as `int` column but the default is a string named `active`. That won't work.

Comment: What should i define here string?

Comment: If it's an `integer` you can use `->default(0)`

Comment: @AnvitaRastogi: You should define what your programs expects. Actually you have to know what you want for that column - a string or a number.